# Replace de X a 0 C#

Tags: c#, str-replace

Estoy haciendo insert de un grid, con un debbug me doy cuenta que si estoy recibiendo los datos, algunos son decimal, como ven hago la conversion, pero resulta que en estos puede haber una 'X' por lo que me lanza una exception,

Por lo que necesito que si su valor de estos es una X lo cambie por un 0(cero) y que de esta manera ya pueda hacer el insert correctamente.

Como puedo lograrlo?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in datagrid.Rows)
{
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Stock", item.Cells[2].Value.ToString()); 
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Cant", float.Parse(item.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Units", float.Parse(item.Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el `TryParse()` de esta forma defines un valor por defecto y si la `X` no deja convertir correctamente no pasara nada

Algo como esto

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in datagrid.Rows)
{
    float cant = 0;
    float.TryParse(item.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out cant);

    float unit = 0;
    float.TryParse(item.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out unit);

    comando.Parameters.Add(":Stock", item.Cells[2].Value.ToString()); 
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Cant", cant);
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Units", unit);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Si el problema es la cultura que tienes aplicada podrias usar

```
float cant = 0;
float.TryParse(item.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out cant, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

asi te aseguras que al recibir un valor numerico con el punto como separador decimal lo reconozca

Comment: Si me esta asignando 0 en los campos, pero los esta poniendo en todos, es decir, aveces puede haber una X otras puede tener un 1.5, lo cual es correcto, pero checando aunque tenga un punto decimal lo reemplaza a 0, por lo que necesito que haga un replace de X a 0 en caso necesario.

Comment: puede deberse a la configuracion regional, y este esperando una coma como separador, si usas una cultura en-US el punto es el separador

Answer (score 6):

Hazte un funtor auxiliar en tu contexto de trabajo:

```
Func<Cell, Float> numero = c =>
{
    float resultado = 0;
    float.TryParse(c.Value.ToString(), out resultado);
    return resultado;
};

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in datagrid.Rows)
{
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Stock", numero(item.Cells[2]));
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Cant",  numero(item.Cells[3]));
    comando.Parameters.Add(":Units", numero(item.Cells[4]));
    .
    .
    .
}
```

El funtor anterior devuelve `0` si el valor no pudo ser convertido a número.